# Typescript functions : What does the ":" type" after parameters mean & why some functions don't have it?

Tags: typescript, function, return-type, typechecking, inferred-type

## The question

#### **In a nutshell :**

(It's in the title of the question)

- ":" after function parameters, what does it mean?
- Why is it not always present ?

#### **With examples :**

I could see a lot of different ways to write a function in Typescript, for instance :

**Ex 1**

```js
function buildName(firstName: string, lastName: string) {
  return firstName + " " + lastName;
}
```

but also,

**Ex2**

```js
function buildName(firstName: string, lastName: string): string  {
  return firstName + " " + lastName;
}
```

I couldn't really figure out why if what comes after "function(params):" is a type, why isn't it always present. For example, in Java or C++, a function always tells what type of stuff it returns. When the function returns nothing, this is still indicated in these languages as `void`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The Answer

#### **In a nutshell :**

- ":" - after function parameters, introduce the type of what's returned by the function.
- not always there? - Typescrict can infer the type of what is returned by the function.

#### **With the previous examples :**

Typescript's ": type" after function parameters is there to **tell of what type is the stuff return by the function** like in Java or C++. However, **Typescript by default [infers the return type of the function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#inferring-the-types)** so that it's not always necessary to explicitly write it in the code.

In **Ex1** the function `buildName` returns `firstName + " " + lastName` which is composed of `strings`. Hence the compiler knows that the function returns a `string`.

In **Ex2** the function `buildName` has `: string` after it's parameters. This means that the programmer explicitely tells that the function returns a `string`. This can be helpful as the compiler will check that what's returned by the function is really a `string` or not. If it's not, it will throw an error which can tell the programmer that he did a mistake since the function is not behaving as expected.

Here are some good resources I used to learn functions in Typescript:

[Typescript Handbook: functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html) - The official handbook for typescript.

[Typing functions in TypeScript | 2ality](https://2ality.com/2020/04/typing-functions-typescript.html) - A long but rather complete a well-illustrated guide on typescript's function.

NB : There are similar questions on StackOverflow but not matching what I searched. I decided to do my own.